# How to merge two arrays with same id?

Tags: php, arrays

first arrays has two properties:

id, text

second array has two properties
id, count

How to combine these into one array by id where the new array will have three properties:

id
text
count

First array:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#351 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["text"]=>
    string(5) "tree"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#348 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["text"]=>
    string(8) "house"
  }
```

second array:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#351 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["count"]=>
    string(5) "3"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#348 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["count"]=>
    string(8) "4"
  }
```

I tried:

array_merge_recursive, array_merge where these only merge the two arrays together into one long array.

Expected output with above arrays:

```
 array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#351 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["count"]=>
    string(5) "3"
    string(1) "1"
    ["text"]=>
    string(5) "tree"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#348 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["count"]=>
    string(8) "4"
    string(1) "2"
    ["text"]=>
    string(8) "house"
  }
```

Comment: There is no API for deep merge. You need to iterate and merge yourself

Comment: You could try `array_merge_recursive`

Comment: @Philipp, I tried that, but it merge them all into long array.

Comment: You need to iterate and check existance in second array by element id field, and if that happens, then maybe output a new element into a new array mixing arr1 and arr2 fields so you make your desired mix in lets say arr3

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple function that would merge the properties of the object in the second array if it matches the id of the object in the first array:

```php
function obj_array_merge( $a1, $a2 ) {
    $newAry = [];
    foreach( $a1 as $idx => $obj1 ) {
        // Clone object to prevent alterations to object in $a1
        $newAry[$idx] = clone $obj1;
        foreach($a2 as $obj2) {
            /**
            ** If id property of both objects match,
            ** copy properties from second array object
            ** to new object (clone of first array object).
            */
            if( $newAry[$idx]->id === $obj2->id ) {
                foreach($obj2 as $prop => $val) {
                    $newAry[$idx]->$prop = $val;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $newAry;
}

// To run:
$mergedArray = obj_array_merge( $array1, $array2 );
```

However, note that this is not going to be fast. With a large number of objects it can get quite slow since it has to iterate over both arrays to check for matches. It will also overwrite properties that exist in the new array object with that of the second array object (you didn't specify if that was an issue).